# Eclipse marketplace update issue

Tags: eclipse

I cannot install Eclipse plugins from Eclipse marketplace, I get following error messages:

[image]

**EDIT :**

I tried multiple times and found a similarity every time: The first half of the installation process finishes quickly (in a couple of minutes), and then the installation process not progressing further than half. (I am using Windows Vista)

[image]

Comment: Do you get more details when you double click the message? (This is a rhetoric question).

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a connection problem. Do you have a proxy set?

Comment: I don't have set a proxy for myself.

Comment: It may be a connection problem, but should be in the Eclipse site. Because I am able to update my Netbeans IDE (and other downloads) without any problems.